# Looking for DTM for Morocco

Tags: data, dem, morocco

I am looking for a DTM for the city of Agadir in Morocco.

Could anyone help me to find it?

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was asked on a [Research Gate forum](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Free_digital_terrain_model_DEM_on_the_web) where you can download:

- [15m DEMs from orthocoverage](http://orthocoverage.tti.fr/download/morocco1.php)
- [30m DEMs from NASA](http://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp)